# How to use the mmap() function in c

Tags: c, fork, mmap

I am trying to read in a large file and map this file to the memory and then divide up the workload by passing different starting and stopping addresses to different processes which will then count all the occurrences of all words in the file. The following code I have checks if it is a file, opens the file to read, and gets the size of the file. I am unsure exactly how to use this mmap() function. Specifically, what goes in mmap() as parameters. What should the offset be and where do I get this value from?

Also, how will this be used to create child processes using fork()?

```
       stat(argv[1], &fileStat);
       // Check if the INPUT is a file.
       if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode)) {
          type = "file";
          file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
          if (!file)
             perror("ERROR: Failed to open the file!");
          // Check the total size of the file
          stat(file, &fileStat);
          size = fileStat.st_size;
          // map file to memory and divide workload by passing different
          // starting address and stopping address to different processes
          addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ , MAP_SHARED , file, off_set);
          // Count word occurrences
          //count_words(file, words);
          fclose(file);
       } else {
          perror("ERROR: Not a file!");
          exit(1);
       }
```

Comment: Read the man-page, it is quite clear: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Answer (score 1):

The offset is where in the file you want the `mmap` to begin. If you want to see the whole file, use an offset of 0.

Your question about `fork` is unclear, `mmap` and `fork` don't really have anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fildes, off_t off);
```

format of call: `pa=mmap(addr, len, prot, flags, fildes, off);`

> The mmap() function shall establish a mapping between the address
>   space of the process at an address pa for len bytes to the memory
>   object represented by the file descriptor fildes at offset off for len
>   bytes. The value of pa is an implementation-defined function of the
>   parameter addr and the values of flags, further described below. A
>   successful mmap() call shall return pa as its result. The address
>   range starting at pa and continuing for len bytes shall be legitimate
>   for the possible (not necessarily current) address space of the
>   process. The range of bytes starting at off and continuing for len
>   bytes shall be legitimate for the possible (not necessarily current)
>   offsets in the file, shared memory object, or typed memory object
>   represented by fildes.

try this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html)

on the fork side try this [link](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)